# Import block to CMS page using {{block ......}} not working after upgrade to Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.4

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have this code it was working well befor upgrade to Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.4 and all codes like this  {{block ......}} are not working now after upgrade. 
This is one of them:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list-home.phtml" column_count="3" products_count="3"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure allowed variables and blocks in `System > Permissions > Blocks` and `System > Permissions > Variables`.

you have to add `catalog/product_list` block there.
This feature was added in Community Edition 1.9.2.2 and Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.2